# Make Spring Resource Prototype

Tags: java, spring, date

I have a constructor with a Date inside, but it always takes the date when you started the server, I think I need something like make protoype my bean.

```
@Service("calendarioBO")
public class CalendarioBusinessImpl implements CalendarioBusiness{

private final String strFechaHoy;
private final String [] segmentos;
private final int mesHoy;
private final int anioHoy;
private final int mesAnt;
private final int mesSig;
private final int anioAnt;
private final int anioSig;

public CalendarioBusinessImpl(){
    strFechaHoy = Fecha.getFechaActual("dd/MM/yyyy");
    segmentos = strFechaHoy.split("/");
    mesHoy = Integer.parseInt(segmentos[1]);
    anioHoy = Integer.parseInt(segmentos[2]);
    mesAnt = mesHoy-1 <= 0 ? 12: (mesHoy-1);
    mesSig = mesHoy+1 >= 13 ? 1: (mesHoy+1);
    anioAnt = mesHoy-1 <= 0 ? (anioHoy - 1): anioHoy;
    anioSig = mesHoy+1 >= 13 ?(anioHoy + 1): anioHoy;
}
}
```

This is my action

```
@Service("calendarioAction")
public class CalendarioAction extends ActionSupport implements   Serializable{
private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(CalendarioAction.class); 

@Resource
private CalendarioBusiness calendarioBO;

}
```

And this is my XML

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.att.prh.business.impl" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.att.prh.llaveMaestra" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.att.prh.connection" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.att.feriavirtual.business.impl" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.att.campania.business.impl" />


<tx:annotation-driven />
```

Comment: Which is expected by you other than one you are getting also where is Fecha coming from

Comment: The default scope of the Spring is singleton. So, when you call the "CalendarioBusiness", the Date can't be changed after it is created. I think you can write separated Util for fetching your Date and call when it is necessary. I don't think changing the Scope to Prototype is the best way. Hope this help.